# Vim common history file across multiple instances of gvim

Tags: vim, history

I want to maintain a common history file across multiple instances of gvim so that when I run a command(like regexp) in one instance I should be able to execute the same command in another instance of gvim. I searched google and couldn't find much help. So, does anyone know how to do this?

Thanks,
Rakesh

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, there is no such feature currently available in Vim / gVim.

It is in the todo list for the future, see `help todo` and search for `top-level` (it is under category 7), but as far as I know, it hasn't been implemented yet.

Comment: I saw the todo and see what you are referring. Thanks a lot for the info.